Creating object profiles based on their attributes
I'm working on a recommendation system to suggest alternative cities based on how similar city A is to the recommendations. To do this, I gathered information about each city's different points of interest, and I set the features for each object to be a number that represents the count of each type of POI/feature. The end goal is to have a city profile where it says sth like city A is 20% nature, 40% culture, 30% gastronomy and 10% nightlife.
The issue is that given the different range of city sizes, I am not sure how I could normalise this data so that differences in counts among the features do not affect the "profile" too much (i.e. a city might be quite famous for a national park but also has lots of museums, even though not so relevant... how could I normalise this so that it's not 1 park vs 10 museums?).
I considered using something like the percentage of surface used by each type of POI, but I was wondering whether there are any techniques or existing approaches that I could consider since I could not find any relevant information about this.
